# AQL: How to get back the path that all edges must have an property(array) and that array must have at least one certain value

Tags: arangodb, aql

Suppose I have an graph like this:

A---edge1---B     property P [P1,P2]

B---edge2---C     property P [P2,P3]

C---edge3---D     property P  [P2,P3]

B---edge4---D     property P  [P1,P3]

And each edge have an property P which is an array of string [P1,P2,P3]. Each edge has their own value of P
Now I would like to return all vertexes that:

1. For Each vertex, check if exist a path where each edges, all of them must have at least P2 in property
2. Depth smaller or equals then 2

**

```
For entity in entities
For v,e,p in Collection in 0..2 ANY entity 
Filter //What should I do here? I tried p.edges[*].P[*] ANY =="P2" 
Collect v._key into groups 
return {key:v._key,group:groups} //Get the vertex that satisfy the condition
```

**

Answer (score 0):

`p.edges[*].P[*]` is an array of arrays. To get `ANY ==` to compare array to individual element would require a flattened array, but then it cannot be determined whether each array has `"P2"`.

One of the following conditions should work however:

- `FILTER p.edges[* RETURN "P2" IN CURRENT.P] ALL == true`
- `FILTER (FOR arr IN p.edges[*].P RETURN "P2" IN arr) ALL == true`
- `FILTER LENGTH(p.edges[* FILTER "P2" IN CURRENT.P]) == LENGTH(p.edges)`